Joining different tables with the same columns but different data
I have 4 tables all with the same layout.
ID, Name, Totals
Each table may have unique and non-unique IDs if the ID and Name is reused but with different totals. For example;
Year1



ID
Name
Totals




1
Bob
15


2
John
2


3
Smith
4


4
Carl
4



Year2



ID
Name
Totals




1
Bob
10


3
Smith
2


4
Carl
1


5
Greg
10



I want to join each table into one query where those with ID that are duplicated to be combined with the Totals field being summed and then Non-unique ID to show their one result.
So the results show as



ID
Name
Totals




1
Bob
25


2
John
2


3
Smith
6


4
Carl
5


5
Greg
10



I can join the tables with a FULL OUTER JOIN which will give me the full results of each table but I don't know how to create the unique columns with the Totals combined.
Currently the script I am using is as follow to test;
SELECT 
COALESCE (Y1.ID, Y2.ID) AS 'ID', 
COALESCE (Y1.Name, Y2.Name) AS 'Name',
Y1.Totals + Y2.Totals AS 'GrandTotal'
FROM Year1 AS Y1 
FULL OUTER JOIN Y2 AS Y2ON Y1.ID = Y2.PlayerID

This will give me the ID column correctly and Name column correctly but the totals are NULL if the Totals has any NULL instance if that ID doesn't appear across all tables.



ID
Name
GrandTotals




1
Bob
25


2
John
NULL


3
Smith
6


4
Carl
5


5
Greg
NULL



The results I want to see are;



ID
Name
Totals




1
Bob
25


2
John
2


3
Smith
6


4
Carl
5


5
Greg
10



I have also tried;
SELECT 
COALESCE (Y1.ID, Y2.ID) AS 'ID', 
COALESCE (Y1.Name, Y2.Name) AS 'Name',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Y1.Totals),0) FROM Year1) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Y2.Totals),0) FROM Year2)  AS 'GrandTotal'
FROM Year1 AS Y1 
FULL OUTER JOIN Y2 AS Y2ON Y1.ID = Y2.PlayerID

This is initially giving a Column ID is invalid as its not contained in a GROUPBY clause.
When adding a group by clause, it is then not recognizing ID as a column
GROUP BY [ID]


"I have 4 tables all with the same layout." mistake #1. Why aren't they all in a single table with a Year column?

You are very close!
Just use COALESCE around both total columns, you don't need subqueries there:
SELECT
  COALESCE(y1.id, y2.id) AS id, 
  COALESCE(y1.name, y2.name) AS name, 
  COALESCE(y1.Totals, 0) + COALESCE(y2.Totals, 0) AS GrandTotals
FROM
  Year1 y1 
  FULL OUTER JOIN Year2 y2 
    ON 
      y1.id = y2.id 
      AND y1.name = y2.name 
      -- you joined on the id columns only, so maybe remove the line above
ORDER BY COALESCE(y1.id, y2.id); -- the ORDER BY clause is optional

See this fiddle with your sample data.

Excellent that sorted it. So simple now that I think about it, I was overcomplicating it in my head.

@AdamTelestoTBKConde the union all answer is probably better

A better way to do this might be to UNION ALL then GROUP BY and sum.
SELECT
  y.ID,
  MIN(y.Name) AS Name,
  SUM(y.Total) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT
      y1.ID,
      y1.Name,
      y1.Total
    FROM Year1 y1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      y2.ID,
      y2.Name,
      y2.Total
    FROM Year2 y2
--  etc
) y
GROUP BY
  y.ID;

Really what you should do is have these in one table in the first place, then you wouldn't have such problems.
